# Is it possible to download the custom sharepoint pages from the internet

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to download custom sharepoint templates from the internet. Because i am not alout to save a sharepoint page to my computer. And i don't have Sharepoint Designer either. I am intrested in the Article page or the Blog page.
Gr .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SharePoint Online, things does not go that way. The template is saved on the cloud and just use it when you need, like this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/page-templates-in-sharepoint-faa92408-0c84-4e3d-8460-3c28065e7873) said.

So you do not need to use any desktop application, as long as you have access to that template and have proper plan to use SharePoint Online, you can directly use it and edit the page using that template in browser.